# Realm: Why when updating an object, it loses its children references?

Tags: ios, realm

I'm writing some Unit tests for my Realm model but I'm getting a problem when updating saved Realm objects. Th problem is about losing the one-to-many references after an update.
Please, see the example below:

(I'm using Quick, but it should be readable even if you don't know it)

```
// Create a test User.
let user = User.init()
user.account_id = 1
user.email = "foo@bar.com"
user.cards.append(Car(value: ["id": 1]))
user.cards.append(Car(value: ["id": 2]))
user.boxes.append(Box(value: ["id": 5]))
user.boxes.append(Box(value: ["id": 6]))

// Save User.
self.testRealm.write { () -> Void in
    self.testRealm.add(user, update: true)
}

// Get User.
let testUser = self.testRealm.objectForPrimaryKey(User.self, key: 1)
expect(testUser).toNot(beNil())

// Update the user by creating a new one.
let newuser = User.init()
newuser.account_id = 1
newuser.email = "fooBar@bar.com"

// Update a test User.
self.testRealm.write { () -> Void in
    self.testRealm.add(newuser, update: true)
}

// Get User again.
let testUpdatedUser = self.testRealm.objectForPrimaryKey(User.self, key: testUserId)
expect(testUpdatedUser?.email).to(equal("fooBar@bar.com"))
expect(testUpdatedUser?.boxes.count).to(equal(2)) <--- FAILS
expect(testUpdatedUser?.cards.count).to(equal(2)) <--- FAILS
```

And my Model:

```
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "account_id"
    }

    dynamic var email = ""

    // The list of Boxes that user owns.
    let boxes = List<Box>()

    // The list of Cars that user owns.
    let cars = List<Car>()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior. Properties, which have nil values, are merged with the existing values if you set the optional parameter `update: true`. List properties may not be nil. An empty list could be also a legitimate more up-to-date value than a list of some objects.

You'd need to retrieve the object and manually merge the properties according to your will.

Comment: Very good point! You're right. An empty array is something and should replace the old value. I realized that I'm initializing the arrays when I create a new object with `List<Box>()` but I couldn't find a way to make it work neither with a `lazy var` nor if I try to initialize only when I append a new value. Do you got any idea?

Comment: It sounds disappointing. I was expecting something easier. That approach kind of kills the `update: true` method for objects with one-to-many references. But thanks a lot man!!

Comment: There would be multiple issues with nullable lists, which prevented us from allowing anything like that. Lists have to be constants, because the reflection APIs don't allow us otherwise to access the linked type and replace the property with dynamic accessors at runtime.